# Replacing a certain character with below pattern using RegEx in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have strings as below:

```
s1 = "My email Id is abcd@g mail.com"
s2 = "john@ hey.com is my email id"
s3 = "id is rock@gmail .com"
s4 = "The id is sam @yahoo.in"
```

I have to replace the blank space in email ID using regex.
How can I achieve this?

I tried

```
s = re.sub(r'@\w*[\s]+[\w]*\.', r'', s1)
```

which is giving me output as:

```
'My email Id is abccom'
```

Output should be:

```
'My email Id is abc@gmail.com'
```

I'm not sure how can I replace only blank value with `re.sub`.

Any Suggestions are welcome

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callable to remove spaces after matching email addresses with spaces using `re.sub`.

```
import re
l = [
    "My email Id is abcd@g mail.com",
    "john@ hey.com is my email id",
    "id is rock@gmail .com",
    "The id is sam @yahoo.in"
]
for s in l:
    print(re.sub(r'[\w.-]+ ?@(?:[\w-]+\.[\w -]+|[\w -]+\.[\w-]+)', lambda e: e[0].replace(' ', ''), s))
```

This outputs:

```
My email Id is abcd@gmail.com
john@hey.com is my email id
id is rock@gmail.com
The id is sam@yahoo.in
```

Comment: I made small change in the question. It works fine if email id is at the end but it's removing spaces between other words to if email id is not at the end. See 2nd string the question.

Comment: I see. Edited my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use back references in `re.sub` ([online regex here](https://regex101.com/r/ckz205/1)):

```
import re

data = [
"My email Id is abcd@g mail.com",
"Email Id: defg@yah oo.com",
"id is rock@gmail .com"
]

for s in data:
    print(re.sub(r'(@.*)(\s+)(.*)', r'\1\3', s))
```

Prints:

```
My email Id is abcd@gmail.com
Email Id: defg@yahoo.com
id is rock@gmail.com
```

EDIT:

If the blank space is before the `@`, the regexp is a little bit tricky (to not match e.g. "aaa bbb ccc k@gmail.com", [online regex here](https://regex101.com/r/ckz205/2)):

```
import re

data = [
"My email Id is ab cd@gmail.com",
"Email Id: def g@yahoo.com",
"id is roc k@gmail.com",
"aaa bbb ccc k@gmail.com"
]

for s in data:
    print(re.sub(r'(?=is|:)(.*)\s+(.*@.*)', r'\1\2', s))
```

Prints:

```
My email Id is abcd@gmail.com
Email Id: defg@yahoo.com
id is rock@gmail.com
aaa bbb ccc k@gmail.com
```

Now we can combine these regexes:

```
import re

data = [
"My email Id is ab cd@gmail.com",
"Email Id: def g@ya hoo.com",
"id is roc k@gm ail.com",
"aaa bbb ccc k@gmail.com"
]

for s in data:
    s = re.sub(r'(@.*)\s+(.*)', r'\1\2', s)
    s = re.sub(r'(?=is|:)(.*)\s+(.*@.*)', r'\1\2', s)
    print(s)
```

Will print:

```
My email Id is abcd@gmail.com
Email Id: defg@yahoo.com
id is rock@gmail.com
aaa bbb ccc k@gmail.com
```

Comment: I have edited my question with one more condition if the blank space is before **@**

Comment: it's not handling if email id is not at the end. See 2nd string in my question.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Just combine these regexes, see my updated answer